# WCF Tracing IIS 6.0 Issue

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-6, trace

I created a virtual directory and deployed my WCF service with Default app pool running on network service Account. I wanted to have WCF trace enabled in the service which is hosted. I modified the configuration to add trace listeners and it worked fine from Visual studio IIS express. Then I copied the configuration and applied onto the server. Tracing is not working there. I made sure log folder exists.

Can somebody help in troubleshooting the issue?

Comment: The log folder must allow Network Service to write.

Answer (score 0):

I gave Modify permissions to Network Service Account and it worked like a charm:)

Comment: Isnt that what Lex Li said in his comment? Credit should go to him. You should have asked him to add his comments as answer and marked it as answer.